# trying to update db values from php form but not reflect any result

Tags: php

here  my php program for same:

```
public function updateUser($id,$name,$lname,$username,$password,$gender,$email,$mobile,$address) {
  printF($id);
  $update = ("UPDATE oops SET firstname = '$name',lastname = '$lname', username= '$username',password='$password',email = '$email', gender = '$gender', mobile = '$mobile' , address = '$address' WHERE uid = '$id'");
  printF($update);
  $result = mysql_query($update);

  if ($result) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Please provide some more information: What output are you getting currently?

Comment: Did your query parse correctly? How do you check if you are connected to the database? Are you sure you have this user Id in the database? Those are the first points  you need to start with.

Answer (score 0):

Try removing () parenthesis from `$update` variable and `DO NOT` use `mysql_*` features , use `mysqli_*` instead of `mysql_*`

```
public function updateUser($id,$name,$lname,$username,$password,$gender,$email,$mobile,$address) {
  printF($id);
  $update = "UPDATE oops SET firstname = '$name',lastname = '$lname', username= '$username',password='$password',email = '$email', gender = '$gender', mobile = '$mobile' , address = '$address' WHERE uid = '$id'";

  printF($update);
  $result = mysqli_query($update);

  if ($result) {
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
}
```